# Problem with Kohana 3.2 Validation class. It seems it is not sending Exception when there is an error

Tags: php, validation, try-catch, kohana-3

When the POST data is send to:

```
Auth::instance()->register( $_POST );
```

The data is then validated... If it's not I assume the Validation Class in Kohana throws an Exception. And then try-catch function catches it. The problem I am having is with this method:

```
$this->send_confirmation_email($_POST);
```

It is called even if the data is not valid. I believed that if the data was not valid it would skip everything else and jump to catch... But it seems I was wrong because I am getting a nasty Fatal error from the method to send an email because it cannot find the email address...

```
try {
        if( ! $optional_checks ) {
           //throw new ORM_Validation_Exception("Invalid option checks");
        }

        $_POST['email_code'] = Auth::instance()->hash(date('YmdHis', time()));

        Auth::instance()->register( $_POST );

        $this->send_confirmation_email($_POST);

        // sign the user in
        Auth::instance()->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        // redirect to the user account
        $this->request->redirect('user/profile');
     } catch (Validation_Exception $e) {
```

So, is there a way so that the method to send an email is skip if the data is not valid?

One could say I should use check() method. Here is why it is a problem:

```
 Validation::factory($fields)
                    ->rules('username', $this->_rules['username'])
                    ->rule('username', 'username_available', array($this, ':field'))
                    ->rules('email', $this->_rules['email'])
                    ->rule('email', 'email_available', array($this, ':field'))
                    ->rules('password', $this->_rules['password'])
                    ->rules('password_confirm', $this->_rules['password_confirm']);

            if (Kohana::config('useradmin')->activation_code) {
                    Validation::factory($fields)->rule('activation_code', 'check_activation_code', array($this, ':field'));
            }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE:**

It seems now that there is a problem with Kohana Validation class.

Here is the method in my Model_User class:

```
public function create_user($fields)
{
    Validation::factory($fields)
        ->rules('username', $this->_rules['username'])
        ->rule('username', 'username_available', array($this, ':field'))
        ->rules('email', $this->_rules['email'])
        ->rule('email', 'email_available', array($this, ':field'))
        ->rules('password', $this->_rules['password'])
        ->rules('password_confirm', $this->_rules['password_confirm']);
        //->labels($_labels);

    if (Kohana::config('useradmin')->activation_code) {
        Validation::factory($fields)->rule('activation_code', 'check_activation_code', array($this, ':field'));
    }

    // Generate a unique ID
    $uuid = CASSANDRA::Util()->uuid1();

    //CASSANDRA::selectColumnFamily('UsersRoles')->insert($username, array('rolename' => 'login'));
    CASSANDRA::selectColumnFamily('Users')->insert($uuid, array(
                            'username'      => $fields['username'],
                            'email'         => $fields['email'],
                            'password'      => Auth::instance()->hash($fields['password']),
                            'logins'        => 0,
                            'last_login'        => 0,
                            'last_failed_login' => 0,
                            'failed_login_count'    => 0,
                            'created'       => date('YmdHis', time()),
                            'modify'        => 0,
                            'role'          => 'login',
                            'email_verified'    => $fields['email_code'],
                        ));
}
```

The code after the Validation class **is** executed. So even when the data is not valid it still adds a new user to the database.

The test I am doing is with empty inputs.

Here are the rules:

```
protected $_rules = array(
    'username' => array(
        'not_empty' => NULL,
        'min_length' => array(4),
        'max_length' => array(32),
        'regex' => array('/^[-\pL\pN_.]++$/uD'),    
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'not_empty' => NULL,
        'min_length' => array(8),
        'max_length' => array(42),
    ),
    'password_confirm' => array(
        'matches' => array('password'),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'not_empty' => NULL,
        'min_length' => array(4),
        'max_length' => array(127),
        'validate::email' => NULL,
    ),
);
```

Thanks again in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I setup the rules was wrong and the way I setup the Validation custom rules. Here is the code that resolved the problem:

```
protected $_rules = array(
    'username' => array(
        array('not_empty'),
        array('min_length', array(4)),
        array('max_length', array(32)),
        array('regex', array('/^[-\pL\pN_.]++$/uD')),
    ),
    'password' => array(
        array('not_empty'),
        array('min_length', array(8)),
        array('max_length', array(42)),
    ),
    'password_confirm' => array(
        array('matches', array(':validation', ':field', 'password')),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        array('not_empty'),
        array('min_length', array(4)),
        array('max_length', array(127)),
        array('email'),
    ),
);
```

Validation:

```
$validation = Validation::factory($fields)
        ->rules('username', $this->_rules['username'])
        ->rule('username', array($this, 'username_available'), array(':validation', ':field'))
        ->rules('email', $this->_rules['email'])
        ->rule('email', array($this, 'email_available'), array(':validation', ':field'))
        ->rules('password', $this->_rules['password'])
        ->rules('password_confirm', $this->_rules['password_confirm'])
        ->errors('register/user');
        //->labels($_labels);

    if (Kohana::config('useradmin')->activation_code) {
        $validation->rule('activation_code', array($this, 'check_activation_code'), array(':validation', ':field'));
    }

    if(!$validation->check())
    {
        throw new Validation_Exception($validation, __('Your registering information is not valid.'));
    }
```

Thank you all for your support!

Answer (score 1):

There's this thing called an if-else you could use... ;)

Your idea about how the try-catch works is correct: When an exception is thrown inside the try-block, all the remaining code in it is skipped, and it jumps directly into the catch-block.

Most likely the `register` function is simply not throwing an exception like you assumed, which would be the reason your code is not doing what you think it should.

Comment: LOL Dont' worry I though about if-else. But here is my problem. I need to make sure the content in the form is valid. And I am not sure how to know how it was because I though it would throw an error and skip the other code... I think this is more a Kohana problem...

Comment: I added some code to give you a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never used Kohana so I can't really help with it. Perhaps there's inforomation on how to handle this case in Kohana's docs?

Comment: It seems to me that the Exception is not sent... I am trying to figure out why... There is something that I am missing but I just can't put the finger on it. Thanks anyways for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the Kohana Auth class dons't have the method register() as default.

I have implemented this method to use in a specific case, with AmfPHP gateway for Kohana Useradmin module.

The right way is to use the model method to add user and it roles, you will get a throw if the array with fields isn't valid.

You can get the result from `Auth->instance()->register()` like:

```
    if(! Auth::instance()->register( $_POST )) throw new Validation_Exception(...);
```

Try or the best way is to change the `Auth->instance()->register($_POST)` to:

```
    $user->create_user($_POST, array(
        'username',
        'password',
        'email',
    ));
    // Add the login role to the user (add a row to the db)
    $login_role = new Model_Role(array('name' =>'login'));
    $user->add('roles', $login_role);
```

It will make your try catch work as needed for Kohana_Validation exception.

To finish, here is the code from register method, it could help you:

```
/**
 * Register a single user
 * Method to register new user by Useradmin Auth module, when you set the
 * fields, be sure they must respect the driver rules
 * 
 * @param array $fields An array witch contains the fields to be populate
 * @returnboolean Operation final status
 * @see Useradmin_Driver_iAuth::register()
 */
public function register($fields) 
{
    if( ! is_object($fields) ) 
    {
        // Load the user
        $user = ORM::factory('user');
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Check for instanced model
        if( $fields instanceof Model_User ) 
        {
            $user = $fields;
        } 
        else 
        { 
            throw new Kohana_Exception('Invalid user fields.');
        }
    }
    try 
    {
        $user->create_user($fields, array(
            'username',
            'password',
            'email',
        ));
        // Add the login role to the user (add a row to the db)
        $login_role = new Model_Role(array('name' =>'login'));
        $user->add('roles', $login_role);
    } 
    catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) 
    {
        throw $e;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Even when I put: $model_user->create_user($_POST); directly in the controller it still continues the execution... When it should jump to catch. Here the model source code: https://github.com/jnbdz/Kohana-Cassandra/blob/master/classes/model/auth/user.php

Comment: I look in the my Cassandra DB and I can see tones of new users added but without any values for the columns... So it seems the Validation class is not throwing an Exception because if it did it wouldn't have added all those "none-users". So I think the problem is with the Model itself and with Validation... Can you look at the Model_User and tell me what is causing this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also I tried to add $_labels in ->labels(...); in the Validation but I get a error saying that $_labels doesn't exists. But at the top you have that variable being given a value... It does not make any sense.